# Syntax error with exit code

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to check my script with exit codes.

```
        sudo groupmod -n $newname $name 
        sudo usermod -l $newname --move-home --home /home/$newname $name 
        let $exitcode=$?
        echo $exitcode
            if [ "$exitcode" = 0 ]  
            then   
                echo "Everything's ok"
                exit
            elif [ "$exitcode" != 0 ]
            then
                echo "Try again"
                exit 
            fi
```

Here is wath I get :

```
  let :=0 :Syntax error :operand expected (error is "=0")
```

I don't get it. I use the shell buit-in keyword let.

Answer (score 1):

I've made this correction:

`let exitcode=$?` and not `let $exitcode=$?`

That fixes the syntax error.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood you then. I thought the question was still relevant after this fix.